What should my vercel.json config file to deploy my MERN stack given my current project folder organization?
I am trying to deploy my MERN stack on vercel but I can't get much documentation on what the vercel.config file should contain.
This is how my Vite (npm create vite@latest) MERN project is structured:
Project folder structure
the backend files are in the root folder, the front end React files in src folder, and the index.html is in the root folder too.
I also ran a npm run build so I have a dist folder, but it is gitignore (not sure if this is relevant to the deployment).
I have had different variations of vercel.json config file but couldn't get them to deploy the server side in the same project folder. The frontend of the project does show up fine though - I just can't log in / sign up (i.e. make api calls) (they work fine in localhost).
What is wrong with my vercel.json file?
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
    { "src": "server.js", "use": "@vercel/node" },
    { "src": "src", "use": "@vercel/static-build" }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/api/(.*)", "dest": "server.js" },
    { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/src/$1" }  ]
}


Here is how I deployed:
First, do the following:

Install CORS:

npm install cors



Add this code to index.js(Your backend):

app.use(cors({
  origin: [""],
  methods: ["POST", "GET"],
  credentials: true
}));


Leave the origin empty for now; you will add the frontend link after you deploy it on Vercel.

Add this code to your vercel.json file:

{
       "version": 2,
       "builds": [
         {"src": "*.js", "use": "@vercel/node"}
       ],
       "routes": [
         {
           "src": "/(.*)",
           "dest": "/"
         }
       ]
     }



Deploy your backend to Vercel. After deploying, copy the link and add it to the frontend to access the backend:

 await axios.post("THE LINK YOU COPIED/THE ENDPOINT YOU WANT TO
 ACCESS");


You can use POST or GET, as per your choice.

Deploy the frontend to Vercel, then copy the link of your deployed
frontend.

Edit your backend origin where you left it empty:

 app.use(cors({
   origin: ["YOUR FRONTEND LINK"],
   methods: ["POST", "GET"],
   credentials: true
 }));


Now you are set.
If you need a step-by-step guide, see this video on YouTube: https://youtu.be/Cfi0mymfKiA



Thank you, I tried the method that you + youtube posted, however I get error 404 on both front end and back end of the deployment. But here are some concerns

Would it not be scalable if I have to the vercel link into my server.js + included in every API call?
What if you have to change deployment platform?
My file organization is structured differently - unlike the frontend / backend organization structure. With vite, the backend files are in the root folder, and the frontend files is in the root/src folder, I suspect that would affect the vercel configuration file.


did you solve it @jlimsy? same here

Unfortunately no :( I had to deploy it on other hosting services.
